# Statsmodels ztest: Which variance is used in proportions_ztest?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I'm trying to understand how proportions_ztest works

As I understand it when I run

```
stat, pvalue = proportions_ztest(count = 40, nobs = 20000, value = 0.003, alternative = "smaller") 
pvalue
```

it should give the same result for the p-value as

```
stats.norm.cdf(40, 60, np.sqrt(20000* 0.003*(1-0.003)))
```

but it does not. My assumption is, there is a different variance used, but I didnt find any documentation on this.

Comment: what makes you think a **proportions_ztest** is the same thing as a **culmative  distribution function**?

Comment: @DrBwts The documentation says "Test for proportions based on normal (z) test" and "This uses a simple normal test for proportions. It should be the same as running the mean z-test on the data encoded 1 for event and 0 for no event so that the sum corresponds to the count."

Comment: but why do you think that a [z-test](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/z/z-test.asp) is the same thing as a [culmative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)?

Comment: Because the p-value of a z-test equals the cdf at respective point (for a "smaller than" test as set up above). To clarify I only talk about the p-value here.

Comment: SciPy does not have the function `proportions_ztest`.  Could you verify that you are using the function [`proportions_ztest`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) from `statsmodels`?

Comment: Apologies, statsmodels.stats.proportion is correct

Answer (score 0):

statsmodels proportions_ztest uses by default the variance based on the estimated proportion and not the variance base on the null proportion.

One interpretation of this is that the default is a Wald test and not a score test.

see answer and comments here
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447462/why-does-the-proportions-ztest-function-in-statsmodels-produce-different-values

Comment: thanks, but I still dont get the same result. Could please someone take the proportions_ztest line and write it as norm cdf?